# Jetpack Compose: Row of "AndroidView" with dynamic list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In a ViewModel I maintain a list of strings. If `onAddTag` or `onRemoveTag` will be performed a mutableState will be refresh. Which causes a recomposition.

The problem is that if I remove a element (eg the third) with `onRemoveTag` the updated list arrivies in my "Custom Composable" (debugged) but the rendering only removes the last item from the list.

*Example:*

- Initial List: 1,2,3,4 -> onRemove(2) -> Updated List: 1,3,4 -> Renders: 1,2,3
- Initial List: 1,2,3,4 -> onRemove(1) -> Updated List: 2,3,4 -> Renders: 1,2,3

In the Documentation of [`LazyListScope.items`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).items(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) there is this [`key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).items(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) parameter which says:

*key - a factory of stable and unique keys representing the item. Using the same key for multiple items in the list is not allowed. Type of the key should be saveable via Bundle on Android. If null is passed the position in the list will represent the key. When you specify the key the scroll position will be maintained based on the key, which means if you add/remove items before the current visible item the item with the given key will be kept as the first visible one.*

Maybe the `Row` does similar things and it can't properly decide which element needs to be remove and which one stays with the positional information only. But how to fix that?

I do not want do use a `LazyRow` here because I only have a few items to render. Additional to that I want to understand the problem! :)

#### Code

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   var selectedTags = mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())

   fun onRemoveTag(tag: String) {
      selectedTags.value = selectedTags.value.toMutableList().apply { remove(tag) }
   }

   fun onAddTag(tag: String) {
      selectedTags.value = selectedTags.value.toMutableList().apply { add(tag) }
   }
}
```

**MainScreen**

```kotlin
fun MainScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
   val selectedTags by remember { viewModel.selectedTags }

   TagRow(tags = selectedTags)
}
```

***Custom Composable***

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TagRow(
    tags: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        tags.forEach {
            Text(text = it)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope somebody knows how to fix that!

Regards,
Chris

#### EDIT

According to @Philip's feedback I prepared a self-contained example:

```
@Composable
fun StackOverflowPreview() {
    val tags = remember { mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3") }

    Row {
        tags.forEach {
            AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                EmojiTextView(context).apply {
                    textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
                    setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)
                    layoutParams =
                        LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                    text = it
                }
            })
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = tags) {
        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("1")
        
        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("2")
        
        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("3")
    }
}
```

Here you can see that I use [`EmojiTextView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat). If I replace that view with a basic `Text` composable. It works like expected. With the `EmojiTextView` the items will always remove from right to left.

#### EDIT 2

I was able to narrow down my problem to the AndroidView-integration:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun StackOverflowPreview() {
    val tags = remember { mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3") }

    Row {
        tags.forEach { tag ->
            // does NOT work
            // AndroidView(factory = { TextView(it).apply { text = tag } })

            // works
            AndroidView(factory = { TextView(it) }, update = { v -> v.text = tag })
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = tags) {
        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("1")

        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("2")

        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("3")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanna your question to be answered, you wanna make time for an expert to get working sample with reproducible problem as fast as possible. Perfectly I should just paste your code into my sample project and see the problem as fast as I run it. As not sure what's `TagChip`, but with `Text` your code works totally fine. Please update it to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can simulate user actions with `LaunchedEffect`, like: add 1,2,3,4, delay 1 sec, remove 2, so we can see the problem easily

Comment: Also you can replace `mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())` with `mutableStateListOf<String>()` to handle modifications more easily.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? `AndroidView` factory gets called only once, and reused in any next recomposition. And `update` gets called on each recomposition, that's how you need to update any state changes in your `AndroidView`

Comment: My question was a moving target! :) To realize how the AndroidView integration works resolves my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish up this thread here is an working example.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun StackOverflowPreview() {
    val tags = remember { mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3") }

    Row {
        tags.forEach { tag ->
            AndroidView(factory = { TextView(it) }, update = { v -> v.text = tag })
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = tags) {
        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("1")

        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("2")

        delay(2000)
        tags.remove("3")
    }
}
```

As @Philip mentioned in the comments the AndroidView will be just instantiated once and needs a way to update its internal state on recomposition.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MainScreen` Composable, you are wrapping the `val` assignment with `remember`. It causes the list to not be updated on recompositions, so remove that `remember` over there. Then, you have also used a not-so-good approach in the initialization of the `selectedTags` variable in the `viewmodel`. You can directly use delegation inside that, as you have used in your main activity (or composable, as it seems). In your viewmodel, you can initialise the variable as `val selectedTags by mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())`, and then there's no need for using the `.value` prefix everywhere. Rest assured that recompositions **will** be triggered still. You just need to initialise with `mutableStateOf()`.

Also, a better approach of declaring mutable lists, as of Compose 1.0.1, is to use the pre-defined `mutableStateListOf(...)` with which you so not require to use delegation (the 'by' keyword), and can use it just like a regular list object, without any `.value` calls.

Just implement these and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the hints regarding state usage. I will definitely have a look into that. Beside that think the issues are cause by my usage ```EmojiTextView``` (see EDIT)

Comment: I don't think it'd be a problem with the `EmojiTextView`.